# Would anyone know how to load a syncfusion data grid with json data?

Tags: json, xamarin, datagrid, syncfusion

I have successfully collected json data and displayed it on a list view however cant seem to work out how to use sfdatagrid with the json data

i am of beginner level in c# so any help would be much appreciated

here is my code

```
namespace Drip
{

    public class RootObject
    {

        public List<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Channel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated_at { get; set; }
        public string Elevation { get; set; }
        public int Last_entry_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feed
    {
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
        public int Entry_id { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
    }

public partial class DripPage : TabbedPage
{
    private const string Url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/301726/field/1.json";
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    private ObservableCollection<Feed> _data;


   public DripPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

        _data = new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds);
        postsListView.ItemsSource = _data;

        _data= new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds);
        viewModel.ItemsSource = _data;
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    void OnAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void OnUpdate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my JSON data

```
    {
  "channel": {
    "id": 301726,
    "name": "Testing ESP8266",
    "description": "Water meter pulse count",
    "latitude": "0.0",
    "longitude": "0.0",
    "field1": "Water Pulse",
    "created_at": "2017-07-12T12:19:38Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-26T08:41:17Z",
    "elevation": "54",
    "last_entry_id": 151
  },
  "feeds": [
    {
      "created_at": "2017-08-15T13:14:28Z",
      "entry_id": 52,
      "field1": "13.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-08-15T13:14:44Z",
      "entry_id": 53,
      "field1": "13.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-08-15T13:14:59Z",
      "entry_id": 54,
      "field1": "13.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-08-15T13:15:15Z",
      "entry_id": 55,
      "field1": "13.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-08-15T13:15:31Z",
      "entry_id": 56,
      "field1": "13.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:41:38Z",
      "entry_id": 57,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:41:54Z",
      "entry_id": 58,
      "field1": "8.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:42:10Z",
      "entry_id": 59,
      "field1": "8.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:42:26Z",
      "entry_id": 60,
      "field1": "8.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:42:41Z",
      "entry_id": 61,
      "field1": "8.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:42:57Z",
      "entry_id": 62,
      "field1": "11.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:43:12Z",
      "entry_id": 63,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:43:27Z",
      "entry_id": 64,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:43:42Z",
      "entry_id": 65,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:43:58Z",
      "entry_id": 66,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:44:14Z",
      "entry_id": 67,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:44:29Z",
      "entry_id": 68,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:44:45Z",
      "entry_id": 69,
      "field1": "14.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:45:15Z",
      "entry_id": 70,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:45:31Z",
      "entry_id": 71,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:45:46Z",
      "entry_id": 72,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:46:02Z",
      "entry_id": 73,
      "field1": "7.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-05T12:46:18Z",
      "entry_id": 74,
      "field1": "7.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:11:48Z",
      "entry_id": 75,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:12:05Z",
      "entry_id": 76,
      "field1": "5.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:12:20Z",
      "entry_id": 77,
      "field1": "5.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:12:36Z",
      "entry_id": 78,
      "field1": "5.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:12:51Z",
      "entry_id": 79,
      "field1": "5.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:13:06Z",
      "entry_id": 80,
      "field1": "5.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:13:21Z",
      "entry_id": 81,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:13:37Z",
      "entry_id": 82,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-07T18:13:52Z",
      "entry_id": 83,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:25:31Z",
      "entry_id": 84,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:25:51Z",
      "entry_id": 85,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:26:08Z",
      "entry_id": 86,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:26:28Z",
      "entry_id": 87,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:27:00Z",
      "entry_id": 88,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:27:18Z",
      "entry_id": 89,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:27:34Z",
      "entry_id": 90,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:27:49Z",
      "entry_id": 91,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:36:06Z",
      "entry_id": 92,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:36:22Z",
      "entry_id": 93,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:36:39Z",
      "entry_id": 94,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:36:56Z",
      "entry_id": 95,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:37:11Z",
      "entry_id": 96,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:37:28Z",
      "entry_id": 97,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:37:44Z",
      "entry_id": 98,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:37:59Z",
      "entry_id": 99,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:38:37Z",
      "entry_id": 100,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:38:54Z",
      "entry_id": 101,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:39:21Z",
      "entry_id": 102,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:39:36Z",
      "entry_id": 103,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:39:55Z",
      "entry_id": 104,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:40:14Z",
      "entry_id": 105,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:40:35Z",
      "entry_id": 106,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:40:51Z",
      "entry_id": 107,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:41:08Z",
      "entry_id": 108,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:41:27Z",
      "entry_id": 109,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:41:42Z",
      "entry_id": 110,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:48:27Z",
      "entry_id": 111,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:48:43Z",
      "entry_id": 112,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:49:01Z",
      "entry_id": 113,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T08:49:20Z",
      "entry_id": 114,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T09:01:34Z",
      "entry_id": 115,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T09:02:10Z",
      "entry_id": 116,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T09:02:28Z",
      "entry_id": 117,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T09:02:58Z",
      "entry_id": 118,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T09:11:58Z",
      "entry_id": 119,
      "field1": "2.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T09:12:13Z",
      "entry_id": 120,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T12:56:31Z",
      "entry_id": 121,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T12:56:47Z",
      "entry_id": 122,
      "field1": "9.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T12:57:02Z",
      "entry_id": 123,
      "field1": "9.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T12:57:17Z",
      "entry_id": 124,
      "field1": "9.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T12:57:32Z",
      "entry_id": 125,
      "field1": "9.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:02:46Z",
      "entry_id": 126,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:03:03Z",
      "entry_id": 127,
      "field1": "2.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:03:18Z",
      "entry_id": 128,
      "field1": "2.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:03:34Z",
      "entry_id": 129,
      "field1": "2.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:03:50Z",
      "entry_id": 130,
      "field1": "4.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:04:06Z",
      "entry_id": 131,
      "field1": "6.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:04:21Z",
      "entry_id": 132,
      "field1": "6.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:04:36Z",
      "entry_id": 133,
      "field1": "6.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:31:51Z",
      "entry_id": 134,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:32:06Z",
      "entry_id": 135,
      "field1": "1.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-25T13:32:22Z",
      "entry_id": 136,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:07:30Z",
      "entry_id": 137,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:07:47Z",
      "entry_id": 138,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:11:52Z",
      "entry_id": 139,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:12:08Z",
      "entry_id": 140,
      "field1": "2.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:35:34Z",
      "entry_id": 141,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:35:50Z",
      "entry_id": 142,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:36:07Z",
      "entry_id": 143,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:36:24Z",
      "entry_id": 144,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:36:40Z",
      "entry_id": 145,
      "field1": "3.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:36:57Z",
      "entry_id": 146,
      "field1": "4.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:37:13Z",
      "entry_id": 147,
      "field1": "6.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:37:29Z",
      "entry_id": 148,
      "field1": "6.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:37:45Z",
      "entry_id": 149,
      "field1": "6.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:41:01Z",
      "entry_id": 150,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2017-09-26T08:41:17Z",
      "entry_id": 151,
      "field1": "0.00\r\n\r\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

would just need the entry id, date and time and the field 1, data

thanks

*UPDATED CODE*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Drip;assembly=Drip" 
    xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms "
    x:Class="Drip.DripPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="datagGrid" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding _data}">
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>

using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;
using Syncfusion.Data;
using Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Drip
{

        public class RootObject
        {

            public List<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
        }

        public class Channel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Latitude { get; set; }
            public string Longitude { get; set; }
            public string Field1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
            public DateTime Updated_at { get; set; }
            public string Elevation { get; set; }
            public int Last_entry_id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Feed
        {
            public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
            public int Entry_id { get; set; }
            public string Field1 { get; set; }
        }

    public partial class DripPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string Url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/301726/field/1.json";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Feed> _data;

        private SfDataGrid grid;
    }
     protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

            _data = new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds);
           // postsListView.ItemsSource = _data;
            grid.ItemsSource = _data;

            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        void OnAdd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void OnUpdate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a TabbedPage?  That is a container for other pages, it cannot display it's own content.  Where is your SFDataGrid declared and initialized?  Are you sure your data is being deserialized correctly?  Have you looked at the SF walkthrough?  It's really good: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatagrid/getting-started?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Comment: wanting to use a tabbed page for UI and navigation as i was to have a sfdatagrid on one page then charts on another. my sfdatagrid is declared on   the xaml page. yes have looked at the walkthough however only explains loading data locally and not through json. thanks

Comment: you've downloaded the json into _data already - all you have to do is assign dataGrid.ItemsSource = _data;

Comment: Ive tried this however couldnt get it to work, take a look at my code,

Answer (score 0):

1. you have your datagrid defined in both XAML and your code behind.  You only need to do this once
2. you are assigning ItemSource in the XAML and in the code behind.  Again, only do this once
3. you can only databind in XAML if you've defined a BindingContext, which you haven't done
4. you can only databind to public properties, not private variables

   ```
   public partial class DripPage : ContentPage
   {
       private const string Url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/301726/field/1.json";
       private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
       public ObservableCollection<Feed> _data { get; set; }

       protected override async void OnAppearing()
       {
           base.OnAppearing();

           var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
           var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

           _data = new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds);

           this.BindingContext = this;

       }
   ```

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 11:10. Type syncfusion:SfDataGrid not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms

getting this error

Comment: take the trailing space out of the xmlns declaration

Comment: also this exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on this line     LoadApplication(new App());
        }

Comment: I can't debug your entire app for you.  You need to work backwards to figure out where all of these error were introduced - the small snippet of code I gave you shouldn't have done it.  You might consider removing the grid from XAML and just declaring it in code instead.

Comment: showing on the mainActivity.cs, [Activity(Label = "Drip.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;  base.OnCreate(bundle);            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
 LoadApplication(new App()); }

Comment: Ok Thanks for all the help anway! Really Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In SfDataGrid, JSON data cannot bound directly. To bind SfDataGrid with JSON data, you need to deserialize the JSON data to the bindable format. Please refer the below KB link to know how to deserialize the JSON data and bound it to SfDataGrid,

KB link: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7828/how-to-load-sfdatagrid-dynamically-with-json-data-without-poco-classes

Also, we have prepared a sample by binding JSON data to SfDataGrid and you can download the same from the below link,

Sample link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/132918/ze/GridWithJSONData-1403374775